# Problem with fb:chat-invite

Tags: configuration, facebook-chat

I have a iFrame based application.

Here I need to Integrate the facebook chat. I have integrated that by using this script.

```
<fb:serverfbml>
    <fb:chat-invite 
          msg="Hey Rate the Movies. Have fun in knowing latest movie comments and reviews" 
          condensed="false" 
          exclude_ids="1,2,3"/>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Now I can see only the frame which have loading option... But however, the friend list never gets populated.

> Could you please let me know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

That's a **legacy code** ... you should use the new Chat API

> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/